# Python - 'NoneType' Object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python, dijkstra

I am beginner in Python and have been facing this problem for some time. Any suggestions to correct the problem would be valuable.
Below is the code used to find the shortest path, using Dijkstra's algorithm. I have the cost matrix and the source as Input.

```
def dijkstra(cost_matrix,source):
    n = 20
    dist = [0 for row in range(20)]
    visited = [0 for row in range(20)]
    for j in range(20):
        visited[j] = "False"
    visited[source] = "True"
    for i in range(20):
        dist[i] = cost_matrix[source][i]
    prev_min = source
    for k in range(20):
        minimum = min(dist)
        minimum2 = min(minimum,n)
        for i in range(20):
            if dist[i] > (cost_matrix[prev_min][minimum2] + cost_matrix[minimum2][i]):
                dist[i] = cost_matrix[prev_min][minimum2] + cost_matrix[minimum2][i]
        visited[minimum2] = "True"
        prev_min = minimum2
    return dist
```

Code that calculates the cost_matrix

```
def matrix():
    k = 30
    b_ij = [[0 for row in range(20)] for col in range(20)]
    a_ij = [[0 for row in range(20)] for col in range(20)]
    cost_matrix = [[0 for row in range(20)] for col in range(20)]
    for i in range(20):
        for j in range(20):
            rand = random.randint(0,8)
            b_ij[i][j] = rand
            b_ij[j][i] = rand
    while(k > 0):
        rand1 = random.randint(0,19)
        rand2 = random.randint(0,19)
        a_ij[rand1][rand2] = 200
        a_ij[rand2][rand1] = 200
        k = k - 1
    for i in range(20):
        for j in range(20):
            if a_ij[i][j] != 200:
                rand = random.randint(0,8)
                a_ij[i][j] = rand
                a_ij[j][i] = rand
    for i in range(len(a_ij)):
        for j in range(len(b_ij[0])):
            for k in range(len(b_ij)):
                cost_matrix[i][j] += a_ij[i][k] * b_ij [k][j]
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ass1.py", line 60, in <module>
    print(dijkstra(cost_matrix, 1))
  File "ass1.py", line 45, in dijkstra
    dist[i] = cost_matrix[source][i]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Post the entire error message, including the full traceback.

Comment: I second BrenBarn's suggestion, also please correctly format the code you have pasted, as it may also be very important.

Comment: Don't post it in a comment, edit your question to include the traceback and to reformat your code.  Also, you will need to include the code that defines `cost_matrix` or we can't tell how it's failing.

Answer (score 2):

You still haven't posted the actual code where you create the `cost_matrix`.  You posted the code for the matrix function, but not the code where you *use* the matrix function.

However, it looks like the problem is that your `matrix` function doesn't return anything.  It just creates a matrix and throws it away.  You need to add `return cost_matrix` at the end of that function.

Comment: Sorry. Careless Mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Either cost_matrix or cost_matrix[source] has the value None, but it should have been a list.

Print both of them just before the line:

```
dist[i] = cost_matrix[source][i]
```

to find out what the issue is.

By the way, you should probably use numpy for this sort of stuff.